# C++ server cannot read my message from python client via socket

Tags: python, c++, sockets, boost, tcp

I have wrote a python client script to send message to the server via tcp.

```
import socket

TCP_IP = '127.0.0.1'
TCP_PORT = 12003
BUFFER_SIZE = 1024
MESSAGE = b"Hello, World!"

s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
s.connect((TCP_IP, TCP_PORT))
s.send(MESSAGE)
data = s.recv(BUFFER_SIZE)
s.close()

print "received data:", data
```

The server can receive my data, but it seems it cannot read the data. The log info is copied in following.

```
I0328 21:45:24.493249   505 prset04.cpp:210] reading the message (3472609771221168177 bytes)
E0328 21:45:25.493088   505 prset04.cpp:162] unable to receive on socket
I0328 21:45:25.493285   505 prset04.cpp:215] echoing the message
E0328 21:45:25.493479   505 prset04.cpp:185] unable to send on socket
```

What I think is there may be something different between C++ socket module and python's. But I don't know what goes wrong there since I am not familiar with C++ and socket.

Any ideas or explanation will be greatly helpful!

Thanks

server code:

```
static void OnClient(const int sk) {
    size_t len;
    char buf[1024];

    // Read the message length.
    if (!ReadBytes(sk, reinterpret_cast<char*>(&len), sizeof(len))) {
        LOG(ERROR) << "unable to read message length";
        return;
    }

    LOG(INFO) << "reading the message (" << len << " bytes" << ")";

    // Read the message.
    ReadBytes(sk, buf, len);

    LOG(INFO) << "echoing the message";

    // Echo the message.
    WriteBytes(sk, buf, len);
}

static bool ReadBytes(const int sk, char* buf, const size_t n) {
    char* ptr = buf;
    while (ptr < buf + n) {
        if (!SetReadTimeout(sk)) {
            return false;
        }

        auto ret = recv(sk, ptr, ptr - buf + n, 0);
        if (ret <= 0) {
            LOG(ERROR) << "unable to receive on socket";
            return false;
        }

        ptr += ret;
    }

    return true;
}
```

Comment: I don't know how `Python` works but I doubt it sends the length as a binary integer before it sends the message. Maybe it should be `len = ReadBytes(sk, buf, sizeof(buf));`? Also I think you may be calculating your buffer wrong in your `recv()`. Should it be `recv(sk, ptr, n - (ptr - buf), 0);`?

Comment: @Galik The C++ code is provided and should not have problems. It cannot be modified otherwise I will prefer to write a python server.anyway thx!

Comment: Where is the Python equivalent of your C++ `ReadBytes` function?! It seems you forgot to implement the protocol in Python.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like Galik already said, Python doesn't send the length of the string before the string, like your programm expects it. And C/C++ doesn't do this either.

If you want your Python program to work with your C programm, there are several things you have to consider:

1. Use the [`struct`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/struct.html) module to pack your string with the required length before it
2. Use the network byte order when packing your string
3. You should be aware that declarations like `size_t` are architecture dependant and vary between 64 and 32 bit architectures. You can use fixed size integers like `uint32_t` if you want them to be compatible between architectures.

Example Code:

```
from struct import pack
message = "Hello World"
data = pack('!i%ds' % len(message), len(message), message))
```

If you can't change the C-Code to use the network byte order, your specific code should look like this:

```
from struct import pack
message = "Hello World"
data = pack('<Q%ds' % len(message), len(message), message))
```

`<` = Use little endian byte order

`Q` = Use an unsigned 64 bit integer (`sizet_t` on 64Bit architectures)

Comment: Thx for the explanation. I have tried your example, it was close. I got the following info>>received data: o, World!�o��0...... I think I need change the 'i'format to others since it is a 64bit architectures. I have tried 'd' 'q' 'f', they are all failed. I did not find 8bytes long integer format in the python doc. So how can I fix it? Many thx!

Comment: It is not working because the C code is not using network byte order. I've edited my answer with a code example that should work for you.

Comment: WOW, it works perfectly. Thank you so much. I should learn something about network byte order.

Answer (score 0):

As Galik pointed out your python script does not send any length of the message. While your c++ server reads 4 bytes ( 8 if you are on 64 bit linux ) and expect them to be length of the message.
So first 4 bytes are "Hell" which binary form will be quite a big number of bytes your server tries to read.

To fix this - send first 4 bytes as message length in your python script.
Also you'll need to use network byte order ( if you plan to stuck with binary ) to make sure bytes read properly.
Use ntohl() function to convert from network to host byte order number.